# Can Simple Framework handle javax.xml.namespace.QName?

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

[Simple XMLFramework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) does not seem to be able to handle javax.xml.namespace.QName

For example, I would like to have the following XML element

```
<ns:FooModule Name="MyCustomeModule" Type="ns:CustomeModule">
```

matching the following field:

```
@Attribute(name = "Type", required = true)
protected QName type;
```

The framework generates the following exception:

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.AttributeException: Cannot use @org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute(empty=, name=Type, required=true) to represent field 'type' protected javax.xml.namespace.QName
```

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why not use @Namespace

Comment: I am trying to deserialize an XML document. Let's use the example in my original question. I would like parse  Type="ns:CustomeModule" into QName with prefix "ns", namespace URI  "http://www.some.org/ver30/schema", and local part "CustomeModule".